# Cannot find symbol method getTagIterator()

Tags: java, netbeans

Im using netbeans IDE 8.0 jdk 1.8. Im working on school project to extract image metadata. I have found on internet 
http://geekcap.com/campus/Java/article/56 and install the jar files from this link, but the program cannot be run. the error will come out "cannot find symbol" at this this line 97 `for(Iterator i = directory.getTagIterator(); i.hasNext(); )`" and getTagIterator being underlined.

Comment: That error is telling you that directory references to a type that doesn't understand the message "getTagIterator". There isn't much else we can say about it without you showing us more code. At least you need to show which type directory reference is.

Comment: thanks for the respond. i copied the code from this link  http://geekcap.com/campus/Java/article/56 and same goes to the jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source repository of [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/) (linked from the page where you got the code), it looks like the `getTagIterator()` method was removed a while ago with [this commit](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/diff?spec=svn9b141aec05be91988dd2b37d4c0259509c0b246e&r=9b141aec05be91988dd2b37d4c0259509c0b246e&format=side&path=/Source/com/drew/metadata/Directory.java). It was already deprecated before that, and the Javadoc suggests you should use `getTags()` instead. You should be able to replace:

```
for(Iterator i = directory.getTagIterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
    Tag tag = ( Tag )i.next();
    ...

}
```

with:

```
for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But then which part of the code i should specify the image location to be extracted? Thank you in advance

Comment: @iambeginner Do you mean where do you specify the file name of the image? In the link you posted, it takes the file name from the command line arguments, and then passes it to a File constructor: `File jpgFile = new File(filename);`. It's probably best to create a new question if you're having another specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `getTagIterator()` in your object named `directory`. Without more information, we can't really help you further.

Comment: thanks for the respond. Btw, how can i add getTagIterator() method into directory class? it cannot be edited and the class should be there because i have download the jar files given from the same link

Comment: What is `directory`? Chances are you're misspelling or calling the wrong method somewhere...

Comment: But then which part of the code i should specify the image location to be extracted? Thank you in advance